# try Open - Close principle in my code but got strange behavior in java

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-8

```
public interface MainInterface {
}

@Transactional
@Service
@Qualifier("A")
@Primary
public class A implements MainInterface {

}
@Transactional
@Service
@Qualifier("B")
public interface B implements MainInterface {

}
public interface C implements MainInterface {

}
@Service
public class InterfaceFactory {
 public MainInterface getInstance(String type ) {
    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("A") ) {
        return new A();
    } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("B") ) {
        return new B();
    } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("C") ) {
        return new C();
    }else {
     return null;
    }
    }

    }

@Service
public class EventInterceptor {

 public ADTO callEvent(A a, Entity entity) throws URISyntaxException {
  System.out.print("A"); 
}
public ADTO callEvent(B b, Entity entity) throws URISyntaxException {
System.out.print("B"); 
}
public ADTO callEvent(C c, Entity entity) throws URISyntaxException {
System.out.print("C"); 
}
public ADTO callEvent(MainInterface  m, Entity entity) throws 
URISyntaxException {
System.out.print("MainInterface  ); 
}
}

//------------ i'm calling it like so 
MainInterface  obj= interfaceFactory.getInstanceInterface("A");
     gateWayInterceptor.callEvent( obj,entity)));
```

The problem that it always prints MainInterface
and always enter callEvent(MainInterface  m, Entity entity) even if the return type is A OR B OR C this is open close Principle implementation as I understand

I tried to make it generic type the factory but I couldn't 
I tried to remove callEvent(MainInterface  m, Entity entity) but I got exception 
I did the same as the code here in that blog 
https://blog.jetbrains.com/upsource/2015/08/31/what-to-look-for-in-a-code-review-solid-principles-2/ about sold - open close Principle

should enter callEvent(A a, Entity entity) not callEvent(MainInterface  m, Entity entity)

Note i'm using Java 8

Answer (score 0):

I'm not primarily a Java developer but would assume that it's because the obj variable you are passing in to CallEvent is declared as type MainInterface... try casting it as you pass it in, i.e. use "(A)obj" rather than just "obj" and see what you get.

Also, I know you mention you are playing with the Open/Closed principle here but it's worth mentioning this would technically violate Liskov's Substitution Principle which essentially declares that if you do something with a base class you should get the same result if you do that thing with a sub class.